# A class with static methods or class with normal methods

Tags: c++, class, static

I have a utility class which doesn't hold any data members and just provides some services through its methods. In such a case what approach is better, create a class with all static methods or create a class with normal methods and call them by creating an object of the class? What are the pros and cons of either of the approaches?

Comment: Third possible option: use a `namespace` and free functions.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, any reason for choosing either of the three approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the superior choice is using a `namespace` and free functions. Reasons:

- Using a `class` with normal methods is confusing, as it needs to be instantiated but has no state.
- Using a `class` with only static methods is better, but requires the user to always specify the name of the class.
- Using a `namespace` and free functions prevents the possibility of confusing/unnecessary instantiations, and also allows the user to alias the `namespace` or use `using namespace` to avoid repetition when using multiple functions in the same scope. The `namespace` can also span multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no data members, there is no reason to use a class with member methods. You have to create an instance of your class to call your methods (A small, but avoidable overhead)

Calling a static method of a class generates no overhead. The same is for functions in a namespace.